# Were the Egyptian pyramids wireless power stations?

Tags: history, egypt, pyramids

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xk4iLoGpr7A) states many claims, among others:

- the pyramids were built to create "wireless electricity"
- electricity was created by "aquifers" - some mechanism based on water flowing underground
- "negative ions" were transferred to the ionosphere, generating electrical current
- Egyptians used "wireless electricity" for communication purposes
- fine gold plating found on some ancient artifacts requires electricity

Is anything about it feasible?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

> **Is anything about it feasible?**

## Baghdad battery

The video says (at 0:50)  *"electricity was originally generated and widely utilised in ancient Egypt, the Baghdad battery and the first arc lights were used at that time"*

However the dates don't match up.

- [Baghdad battery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baghdad_Battery): between 250 BC and AD 224
- [Egyptian pyramids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egyptian_pyramids) 2630 BCE–2611 BCE

Only a small number of these "Baghdad batteries" were discovered, by contrast the number of Egyptian mummies is in the millions.

Several [alabaster oil lamps](http://www.touregypt.net/museum/tutl28.htm) were found in Tutankhamen’s tomb (but no batteries)

This isn't consistent with electricity being "widely utilised" in "ancient Egypt".

## Soot

At 1:18 the video claims *"No soot has been found in the corridors of the pyramids"* and this is used to suggest thet they therefore must have used electric lighting.

However this is untrue, there is plenty of soot found inside the pyramids. Most of it from visitors in the 18th or 19th centuries, who used oil lamps and candles. When the pyramids were built, the chambers and passageways were constructed in the open, in daylight. The roofs of these spaces were only closed after the work on the spaces was mostly completed/ After that the upper layers could be placed. [Reference](http://www.world-mysteries.com/sar_lights_fd1.htm). In ancient times, visitors were not permitted to enter the sealed tombs of the pharaohs. Once completed there was no need for lighting within.

## Pharos Lighthouse

The video says *"the arc lamp used in the lighthouse of alexandria is further proof that
electricity was used in ancient Egypt, the energy required to power the lighthouse for 24 hours a day could only have been supplied by a regular electrical source"*

Early European and American lighthouses did not require a regular electrical source. They were lit by [open fires, candles and oil lamps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lighthouse#Lighthouse_technology)

## Granite is a conductor

This claim is made at 02:35.

however this is untrue - by any reasonable interpretation of "conductor" in the context of practical transmission of electrical current for powering, for example, a lighthouse.

- [Conductivity of granite](http://www.balkangeophysoc.gr/online-journal/2000_V3/may2000/v3-2-1.pdf) =~ 10<sup>-3</sup> - 10<sup>-7</sup> S/m
- [Conductivity of copper](http://www.ndt-ed.org/GeneralResources/MaterialProperties/ET/Conductivity_Copper.pdf) = 5.8 x 10<sup>+7</sup> S/m

So granite is at least 10,000,000,000 times less conductive than copper.

---

> **This video states many claims, among others:**

## the pyramids were built to create "wireless electricity"

Excavations have shown that the Egyptian pyramids were built to house the tomb of the Pharaohs and their families.

The British Museum [says](https://www.britishmuseum.org/explore/highlights/articles/e/egyptian_pyramids.aspx)

> These monumental stone **tombs** were part of the funerary complexes of the kings of the Old and Middle Kingdoms. Their form developed from the rectangular mastaba tombs of the kings of the Early Dynastic period. The first pyramid, the Step Pyramid of Djoser, consists of six tiers that are like mastabas of decreasing size stacked one on top of the other.

National geographic [says](http://science.nationalgeographic.com/science/archaeology/valley-of-the-kings/)

> The Pyramids of Giza and the Nile Delta were the **tombs** of choice for pharaohs of Egypt's Old Kingdom.

[image]
*sarcophagus in the central chamber of the pyramid at Giza - [From St Louis University](http://euler.slu.edu/%7Ebart/egyptianhtml/kings%20and%20Queens/Khufu.html)*.

According to *A BRIEF HISTORY OF ANCIENT EGYPTIAN TOMBS* at [Dartmouth University](http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/farid/egypt.html)

> Because the king was revered as God, **his tomb (the pyramid)** was constructed to last forever, thus ensuring the continuing prosperity of the king in his afterlife. Like the early mastabas, the 4th dynasty pyramids had no decorations.
>
> The 5th dynasty (Old Kingdom) which saw the construction of more modest pyramids contained the first decorations. These decorations (Fig. 3 and 4) took the form of hieroglyphic writings - known as the Pyramid Texts - which provide guidelines and instructions on how to ensure safe voyage through the nether world and the eternal life thereafter.

Wikipedia cites *Lichtheim, Miriam (1975). Ancient Egyptian Literature, vol 1. London, England: University of California Press. ISBN 0-520-02899-6*. for [Utterance 373](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramid_Texts#Examples) - It can also be found in *The Pyramid Texts, Volume 4 By Samuel Alfred Browne Mercer*

> Oho! Oho! Rise up, O Teti!
> Take your head, collect your bones,
> Gather your limbs, shake the earth from your flesh!
> Take your bread that rots not, your beer that sours not,
> Stand at the gates that bar the common people!
> The gatekeeper comes out to you, he grasps your hand,
> Takes you into heaven, to your father Geb.
> He rejoices at your coming, gives you his hands,
> Kisses you, caresses you,
> Sets you before the spirits, the imperishable stars...

The contents which remain after looting and the inscriptions in chambers in the old-kingdom pyramids in Egypt provide evidence of their purpose.

### "Wireless Electricity"

Electricity is actually a rather [vague notion](http://amasci.com/miscon/whatis.html) but if we take it to mean the movement of charge carriers, wireless electricity would be what we experience in lightning or in the discharge of static electricity. This sort of electricity is much less useful to us than electricity conducted in wires.

## fine gold plating found on some ancient artifacts requires electricity

There are methods for gold plating that do [not require electricity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plating#Electroless_plating)

Comment: An anonymous user tried to comment on this with an edit. They complained there was no evidence to suggest Egyptian pyramids were built to house the tombs of pharaohs. Could you please provide a reference to support that claim?

Comment: @Oddthinking: See revisions to answer.

Comment: I'd +1, but I already have.

Comment: A central part of the theory seems to hinge on the belief that the pyramids are far older than cited (10,000 BCE), and that the ancient Egyptians claimed them for themselves. The various other pyramids in the area are claimed to be failed attempts by the ancient Egyptians at reproducing the grand pyramids on the Giza strip. This theory, of course, has many flaws. In fact, the very point about the lack of soot within the pyramids discredits this idea, as the ancient Egyptians undoubtedly would have used torches to navigate the pyramids had they been beyond their expertise to build.

Comment: [*"Wireless electricity"*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_power) is a specific family of technologies.  It does not refer to lightning or static electricity.

Comment: --Only a small number of these "Baghdad batteries" were discovered, by contrast the number of Egyptian mummies is in the millions.
 
 I'd add that identifying them as batteries a bit of a step. What I've read on them indicates a greater likelihood of them being scroll jars. Likely prayer jars buried under the floor of the house to bless it.

Comment: Also, w.r.t. powering a lighthouse "24 hours a day," a lighthouse isn't really needed at noon.

Comment: @DavidConrad wrong. Lighthouses provide a visible beacon even during daylight, a bright light on the horizon that's visible far beyond where you'd see the tower itself.